# Python Random Int Script Help - Printing Number of Lines

Tags: python, random

here is a script i created that generates 6 random numbers between 1-49, then makes sure none match and prints the result, all works fine except i want to add a number of lines function to print out however many lines i want. this is the problem, i can only get it to print the same numbers 5 times instead of 5 different sets of numbers.

```
import random

def numbers():
    global a,b,c,d,e,f
    a = random.randint(1,49)
    b = random.randint(1,49)
    c = random.randint(1,49)
    d = random.randint(1,49)
    e = random.randint(1,49)
    f = random.randint(1,49)
numbers()
while(a==b or a==c or a==d or a==e or a==f or b==c or b==d or b==e or b==f or c==d or c==e or c==f or d==e or d==f or e==f):
    numbers()
sep = ' '
nums = 'Numbers: '+str(a)+sep+ str(b)+sep+str(c)+sep+str(d)+sep+str(e)+sep+str(f)

print nums
```

is this the most efficient way of doing this, and any ideas to question above?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using `random.sample` for this application. It picks out numbers without replacement, so there's no need for any of the uniqueness checks later on. This function takes a list of the elements to choose from and the number of elements to pick without replacement. Since we want it to pick from the numbers 1 to 49, we can use `range(1, 50)` to create that list.

Second, don't keep each number in a separate variable, simply return it in a list. This is how `random.sample` returns it by default, so just use that.

Third, there's no need to be using globals here. Simply return the list of numbers from the function, assign it to a variable, and use it later.

Fourth, for printing, use `' '.join(list_of_strings)` to automatically insert separators. Of course, first we're going to have to convert the list of integers that `random.sample` returns to a list of strings, which we can do with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This method has the benefit of working with any amount of numbers, as long as you store them in a list first.

Putting that all together:

```
import random

def random_numbers(n):
    return random.sample(range(1, 50), n)

numbers = random_numbers(6)
numbers_str = ' '.join([str(num) for num in numbers])
print('Numbers: ' + numbers_str)
```

I'm not sure what the "number of lines" feature is supposed to be. Do you simply want to repeat the above operation multiple times? Then you just need to repeat the operations above however many times.

```
num_lines = 10

for i in range(num_lines):
    numbers = random_numbers(6)
    numbers_str = ' '.join([str(num) for num in numbers])
    print('Numbers: ' + numbers_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a `set` cannot contain any non-unique values. So I would just keep generating random numbers and trying to add to your `set`. Once the `set` reaches a size of `6` you know you have `6` unique values. Then you can print your set, or convert to a list, or whatever you want to do with it.

```
import random
s = set()
while len(s) < 6:
    s.add(random.randint(1,49)) 

>>> s
set([2, 6, 10, 43, 13, 47])
```

As a function that makes a set of a certain size `setSize` from values 1 up to `maxVal`

```
def makeRandomSet(setSize, maxVal):
    s = set()
    while len(s) < setSize:
        s.add(random.randint(1,maxVal))
    return s
```

Testing the function

```
>>> makeRandomSet(10, 30)
set([3, 5, 11, 14, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29])
```

Comment: great way of efficiency there thanks, any ideas how would go about adding a number of lines (-l) feature?

Answer (score 1):

How about just doing it all at once using built in functions?

```
import random
random.sample(range(1,49),6)
```

Sample output

```
[45, 37, 24, 15, 38, 48]
```

Comment: No need to use numpy or to make it into a set. Simply use the built-in `range` (or `xrange` on 2.x) function as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two improvements. Use a while loop in `numbers` to generate unique random numbers. Then to print them use the `sep.join` function.

```
import random

def numbers():
    n = []
    while len(n)<6:
        x = random.randint(1,49)
        if x not in n:
            n.append(x)
    return n

sep = ' '
for row in range(5):
    print( 'Numbers: '+ sep.join(str(x) for x in numbers()) )
```